# Removing parentheses as unwanted text in R using gsub

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to clean up a column in my data frame where the rows look like this:

```
1234, text ()
```

and I need to keep just the number in all the rows.  I used:

```
df$column = gsub(", text ()", "", df$column)
```

and got this:

```
1234()
```

I repeated the operation with only the parentheses, but they won't go away. I wasn't able to find an example that deals specifically with parentheses being eliminated as unwanted text. `sub` doesn't work either.

Anyone knows why this isn't working?

Comment: thanks David. That code gives me the number as a vector, but I need to do that to all the rows in the datafame. And if I run   df$column = gsub("\\D", "", "*, text ()")   (# replacing the number for a wildcard *)  the whole text disappears.

Comment: Doesn't `gsub("\\D", "", df$column)` work on all the rows for you? If you want your specific code to work, do `gsub(", text ()", "", df$column, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: I got back a vector, but it's ok, I can add it back to the dataframe.  However, this converted my numbers. The originals were floats, negative and positive, and now they're all postive integers.  e.g.  -2.70 got converted to 270

Comment: Did `gsub(", text ()", "", df$column, fixed = TRUE)` work?

Comment: Or `gsub("[A-Za-z(), ]", "", df$column) `?

Comment: No, I still have the parentheses.

Comment: `gsub("[A-Za-z(), ]", "", "-2.7, text ()")` removes the parentheses.

Comment: gsub("[A-Za-z(), ]", "", df$column)    worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses are stored metacharacters in regex. You should escape them either using `\\` or `[]` or adding `fixed = TRUE`. But in your case you just want to keep the number, so just remove everything else using `\\D`

```
gsub("\\D", "", "1234, text ()")
## [1] "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column always looks like a format described above :

```
1234, text ()
```

Something like the following should work:

```
string extractedNumber = Regex.Match( INPUT_COLUMN, @"^\d{4,}").Value
```

Reads like: From the start of the string find four or more digits.